# Error Message in If operator while using color code

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am receiving the below error message when I write the code in fill option in powerapps.

[image]

My code as below

```
If(
   ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "ABC") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 80 ||
    ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "DEF") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 360,
    RGBA( 220, 20, 60, 1 ), RGBA( 127, 255, 212, 1 ));
    If(
    ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "GHI") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 40 ||
    ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "JKL") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 180,
    RGBA( 220, 20, 60, 1 ), RGBA( 127, 255, 212, 1 ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `;` operator (chaining operator) is used to execute multiple operations together - but it only works in a *behavior property*. Fill is a *data property*, so you cannot use it there.

From the expression it seems like you want to have the fill be one of two colors (`RGBA(220, 20, 60, 1)` or `RGBA(127, 255, 212, 1)`). If you want the first color to be chosen if any of the two conditions are true, then you can use the Or function (or operator) to combine those:

```
If(
   ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "ABC") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 80 ||
    ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "DEF") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 360 ||
    ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "GHI") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 40 ||
    ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "JKL") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 180,
    RGBA( 220, 20, 60, 1 ), RGBA( 127, 255, 212, 1 )
```

Notice that this works because the `||` operator has a lower priority than the `&&` operator, but I find it useful to be more explicit and use parenthesis to make it clearer:

```
If(
   (('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "ABC") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 80) ||
    (('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "DEF") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 360) ||
    (('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "GHI") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 40) ||
    (('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "JKL") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 180),
   RGBA( 220, 20, 60, 1 ),
   RGBA( 127, 255, 212, 1 ))
```

Or even use the Or function (which behaves the same as the `||` operator):

```
If(
  Or(
    ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "ABC") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 80,
    ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "DEF") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 360,
    ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "GHI") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 40,
    ('User Input - Unit'.Selected.Value = "JKL") && ('User Input - Application'.Selected.Value = "XXX") && Value('Output'.Text) > 180
  ),
  RGBA( 220, 20, 60, 1 ),
  RGBA( 127, 255, 212, 1 ))
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!